# Docker logs stop logging to console when followed

Tags: docker, logging, file-descriptor

I am running into what feels like [the observer effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics)) with regards to my Docker logs. I am running `docker-compose logs -f containerName` and the logs begin to print to my console. I happen to be using hot reloading in my JavaScript app such that modifying a file then saving it will trigger a hot reload which will be documented in the logs I am following. The hot reloading is controlled via gulp tasks that call on browserSync.

The hot reloading seems to appear in the logs as expected if I run it only a couple of times. If I wait an extended period of time (minutes), triggering a hot reload no longer appears in the logs. If I quit following the logs then immediately begin following them again, I can see that the most recent hot reload was logged, it just was not being previously displayed. This leads me to believe that something probably related to processes and file descriptors is causing this behavior.

Almost as if the process that is running the log following no longer is receiving the output from the logs. It also seems to happen inconsistently in that different numbers of hot reloads will get logged before they cease to be logged each time I run the docker logging command. Any suggestions to as how I can ensure that my logs are always printing new log info would be appreciated. Additionally an explanation as to what is causing this underlying behavior would be a bonus.

Running "Docker Desktop" (formerly called Docker for Mac?)

Version 2.0.0.0-mac78 (28905)

Engine: 18.09.0

Comment: Which platform are you running Docker on? If you're running via moby on windows or hyperkit on OSX then this is related to the following docker issue: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30046 ... I've found that the best way to watch logs in realtime is to have the logs output to a logfile in a host mounted volume (https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume) , and use the usual methods (lnav, tail, etc ...) to monitor the log.

Comment: @eurythmia I've updated the post to include my versions. The mounted volume solution seems very cumbersome. I am seeing multiple online plugins/packages that can be used to do this but that seems like it is more effort than it is worth. I've only noticed this issue as of ~1 month ago and certainly can't be the first to experience this behavior.

Comment: No, it's been hanging around for well over a year now. I discovered it in docker for mac around june 2017. The bug I linked is targeted at the windows version, but D4M suffers from the same issue. I don't have any other solutions for you as I wiped OSX off of my macbook in favor of linux shortly thereafter because there were just too many issues with D4M. Besides myself, there are a few other D4M "me too"s on the above linked issue, but no acknowledgement from the docker team.

Comment: Unfortunate for sure. Thank you for your help.